# Execution stuck in Constructor - power bi visual constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor, powerbi

I´m trying to port my Custom Visual to the new Developer Plattform. After multiple changes I´m able to compile and start the visual. But now, when I want to put Data into the visual, it just shows nothing. After some debugging I found out, that the Visual seems to be stuck in the constructor method, as the update method is never called.

The code in the constuctor looks like this

```
constructor(options: powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualConstructorOptions) {
            this.selectionManager = options.host.createSelectionManager();
            this.options = options;
            // Create main DIV used for the table
            this.root = d3.select(options.element/*.get(0)*/)
                .append('div')
                .classed(FormattedColumnsVisual.VisualClassName, true);
        }
```

the two properties selectionManager and root are defined like this:

```
private root: D3.Selection;
private selectionManager: ISelectionManager;
```

So, the visual executes up to the this.root = .... call. Here it seems to be stuck. I don´t get an error Message, but every line of code after this, just doesn´t get executed.

Maybe you have an idea, what could cause this behavior.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure it gets stuck? You could use web dev tools to inspect dom to see if that div is created. Or you could call window.alert() after the last line of constructor.

Comment: Have you seen the [bar chart example](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart) which uses the new api?

Comment: Yes, I tryed to use the 1.2.0 API version. However, with the 1.1.0 version works now without any problems.